# Does Arrays.toString() override Object's toString() method?

Tags: java, overriding, tostring

Hello everyone this is making me confuse...

All the [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) methods in `Arrays` class are static, so does this really override `Object`'s toString() method? Someone told me that:

> No, it doesn't override Object's toString method. It contains the inherited toString from Object, which is never used since one cannot instantiate the class. What you see in Arrays class, is overloaded versions of toString.

So I went to the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java) but didn't see such thing. Am I missing some thing? sorry for asking such a noob question.

Comment: What did you expect to see and didn't see ?

Comment: I expect to see an inherited `toString()` method from Object class but hadn't been used(means has nothing inside the body).

Comment: @tintinmj. When we say that a class inherits the method from it's super class, that is really different from re-defining that method, in which case it would be called overriding. You should search for the term - `Inheritance`, and read about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Arrays` class is a utility class. As it isn't instantiable, Object's `toString` method is irrelevant.

The static `toString` methods you see are totally unrelated to the standard `toString` method, as should be clear from [their description in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28boolean%5B%5D%29). Note also the plural form : there's more than one method with this name and none of them has the same signature as the Object's one : they all take some argument.

Comment: So `toString` method of `Arrays` class is a standalone method, it has nothing to do with `Object`'s `toString`.

Comment: Only a vague similarity of intent : making a string.

Comment: In one case it's the receiver of the method, in the other case it's the parameter, but yes.

Comment: You might use `Arrays.toString` to help you _implement_ `Object.toString`, though.

Answer (score 0):

`Object`'s `toString()` method has no arguments. All the `toString` methods in `Arrays` have arguments of one sort or another, so they don't override the `toString()` method inherited from `Object`. They are distinct methods that have no relationship (as far as the compiler is concerned) with `Object.toString()`. To use the inherited `toString()` instance method, though, you would need an instance of `Arrays` to invoke the inherited method, and since you cannot have one of those, it is of no consequence.